# Time complexity for merging two sorted arrays of size n and m

Tags: sorting, complexity-theory

I was just wondering what is the time complexty of merging two sorted arrays of size n and m, given that **n is always greater than m**.

I was thinking of using merge sort, which I assume in this case will consume O(log n+m).

I am not really good with big-oh and stuff. Please suggest me the time complexity for this problem and let me know if there is an even optimized way of solving the problem.

Answer (score -14, accepted):

**Attention! This answer contains an error**

A more efficient algorithm exists and it is presented in another answer.

---

The complexity is O(m log n).

Let the long array be called `a` and the short array be `b` then the algorithm you described can be written as

```
  for each x in b
      insert x into a
```

There are m iterations of the loop. Each insertion into a sorted array is an O(log n) operation. Therefore the overall complexity is O (m log n).

Since `b` is sorted the above algorithm can be made more efficient

```
  for q from 1 to m
      if q == 1 then insert b[q] into a
      else 
         insert b[q] into a starting from the position of b[q-1]
```

Can this give better asymptotic complexity? Not really.

Suppose elements from `b` are evenly spread along `a`. Then each insertion will take `O(log (n/m))` and the overall complexity  will be `O(m log(n/m) )`. If there exists  a constant `k>1` that does not depend on `n` or `m` such that `n > k * m` then `O(log(n/m)) = O(log(n))` and we get the same asymptotic complexity as above.

Comment: The operation can be done in O(m+n) = O(n) since m<n. Use the arrays like queues by keeping a pointer to the next element to be used in each array, compare both values before inserting them in the new array. There are exactly n+m comparisons, runtime is O(n). Depending on how different m and n are (for example, if m is in Theta(n)), your solution may be logarithmically slower than that. It may also be exponentially faster if for example m is in O(1).

Comment: Btw sorry for the downvote - I originally thought your answer simply was inefficient, but have come to understand it isn't. SO won't let me upvote again though unless the answer is edited; maybe you could do that?

Comment: "Therefore the overall complexity is O (m log n)." Insertion into an array of n elements is itself an O(n) operation because every element has to be shifted to right. So would O(m * log n) in quoted sentence above actually be O (m*n* log n)?

Answer (score 35):

The time to merge two sorted lists is definitely not O(m log n).  It is O(n+m).

The code looks something like this:

```
allocate c with length n+m
i = 1
j = 1
while i < n or j < m
  if i = n
    copy rest of b into c 
    break    
  if j = m
    copy rest of a into c
    break
  if a[i] < b[j]
    copy a[i] into c
    i=i+1
    continue
  Else #b[j] =< a[i]
    copy b[j] into c
    j=j+1
    continue
```

Now if we don't have enough memory to allocate c this can be modified to still be O(n+m) time as most hardware (both RAM and hard disks for instance) allow for block operations. when we need to insert a single item into the middle of the array it is a single operation to move the tail end of the block over one to make room.  If you were on hardware that didn't allow this then you'd perhaps have O(n) for each insert, which would then be O(n+mn) complexity.  Since we only need to insert elements of the smaller array into the larger we never need to shift pieces of the larger array when the element from that one is already in the right place.  Hence, the n stays the same and the complexity of the m-bit is increased.  This is worst case shown when all of array b with length m is properly placed in front of array a of length n.

Edit: changed last if to else and made original if logic into a comment and added and equal sign to cover that case.  **Psuedocode not intended to be optimized.**

Comment: Depending on whether m is in Theta(n) or not makes O(n+m) slower than O(m log n). I didn't check your algorithm, but it definitely can be done in O(n), see my comment on the answer by Dmitri.

Comment: Shouldn't we consider the case: a[i] = b[j]?

Comment: This answer is wrong: O(n+m) is not better than O(n log(m))! It is fairly easy to see that these complexities are not monotone. On one hand if we set m = n^k for k large then O(n+m) is much worse than O(n log(m)), while on the other hand O(n+m) is better than O(n log(m)) when m ~= n. There is a discussion of this in Section 5.3.2 of TAOCP, some other algorithms are proposed.

Comment: Harry maybe you missed where the OP stated n>m or where the two arrays are already sorted.  As G. Bach mentioned the real Big O for this is actually O(n) since that notation generally simplifies things to that level (i.e. n and n+m both represent a linear growth in time with increase in input and so you use the more be simple expression).

Answer (score 3):

Just going through this problem myself, and the Big O is not `O(m+n)`, it's actually just `O(n)`.

Here's why in Pseudo Code:
(**NOTE:** I wrote this code to handle the cases of **m > n** or **m == n**)

```
Merging sorted arrays A and B into C.
let ints 'i' and 'j' and 'k' = 0

while(i < A.length && j < B.length){
    if(A[i] < B[j]){
        C[k] = A[i]
        i++
    } else {
        C[k] = B[j]
        j++
    }
    k++
}

// Copies rest of A into C if A.len > B.len
while(i < A.length){ 
    C[k] = A[i]
    k++
    i++
}

// Copies rest of B into C if A.len < B.len
while(j < B.length){ 
    C[k] = B[j]
    k++
    j++
}
return C
```

Now all we know is that array of length **n** is larger than array of length **m**. This means there's a possibility that every element in array of length **m** could be greater than every element in array of length **n**, even though **n > m** (such as `A[2,3,4,5,6]` and `B[7,8,9]`), we don't know, it doesn't matter. The first loop will iterate until `i` or `j` is equal to the length of their respective arrays, then only one of the next two while loops will run until the rest of A or B is added to C.

So it can be seen how you end up with `O(m+n)`, however, Big O typically handles *worst case runtime*, therefore we know that we'll iterate over the array of length **n** more times than **m**, regardless of the makeup of the elements inside the arrays, so **m** will always be less than **n**. So we drop the **m** to get `O(n)`.

This is because **n** could equal *infinity*, and therefore since that's a possibility, then we know for a fact that **m** could never be *infinity*, and by definition **must be less than infinity**, and therefore by further definition **has a constant value less than n** (since it stops growing to infinity at some point, as only **n** can be infinite). And since we drop constants when determining the Big O runtime, we get `O(n)`.

Obviously I'm several years late to the party, lol, but I hope that clears up the air for anyone else that may come across this in the future :)