# Time complexity for merging two unsorted arrays of size n and m

Tags: arrays, merge, big-o

Similar to: [Time complexity for merging two sorted arrays of size n and m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039217/time-complexity-for-merging-two-sorted-arrays-of-size-n-and-m) but unsorted.

I'm trying to puzzle out the time complexity of this operation.

You have two arrays of different sizes, you are always merging into the array of greater size. So **n is always larger than m**. You are merging based on a single property of each array element, each time you merge into `Array 1` you remove that element from `Array 2` making `Array 2` shorter.

What would the Big O notation for this be?

Comment: Need more about the problem, because "merge" in the other q. specifically refers to making a sorted array out of two other sorted arrays. Do you want the output sorted, or care about the order otherwise? Do you want items appearing in both arrays to only appear once in the output, or twice?

Comment: Can you pin down some of the restrictions on this problem a little bit? For example, can I allocate additional auxiliary data structures and use them to help with the merge, or is that not allowed?

Comment: @twotwotwo The output does not need to be sorted. I am merging the object from the smaller array into the object in the larger array (Not increasing the length of Array 1), then removing the element from Array 2. 

Think of it as having two list of names, with one list having birthdates, and the other list having favorite colors. I would be merging the objects based on Name.

Comment: Got it--"joining" is a common name for that operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort both arrays. One could assume `O(nlogn + mlogm) = O(nlogn)` (since `n > m`) for this, but if the keys are integers or have other properties that you can take advantage of, you could potentially get closer to the theoretical lower bound of `O(n + m) = O(n)` for the sorting part.

Then for the merge, you only have to spend `O(n + m) = O(n)` because you only have to scan through the arrays once to merge sorted arrays.

In other words, time taken for sorting will dominate, but that's only if you choose to take this algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If `log(n) > m`, it's better to do a dumb linear search and have `O(m * n)` complexity.

Otherwise, sort Array 1 and then you can do fast lookup and have it in `O(n log n)` (sort time only).  The insert is still `O(m log n)` which might dominate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have to search *m* linearly once for each *n*.  On average, you'll find the appropriate position in *m* halfway through.  That makes your complexity

```
O(mn)
```

As mentioned in the comments, although the number of operations is closer to n*m/2, big-O notation ignores linear constants.

I don't think Knuth would approve of the aesthetics, but at least you get the idea.  :-)

Comment: You don't need to specify the "divide by 2" part in big-O notation.  Constant multipliers aren't part of what big-O represents.