# What is the worst-case number of key comparisons of merge?

Tags: merge

> In Mergesort algorithm, the merge function takes as input two sorted
>   arrays of  approximately equal sizes. However, the merge algorithm can
>   also be used to  merge two sorted arrays of very different sizes.
>   Suppose two arrays, A and B,  have sizes 3 and 1000 respectively, and
>   both have been sorted in ascending order. What is the worst-case
>   number of key comparisons of  merge? Justify your answer.

I was thinking that assuming the first 999 element of the size 1000 array is smaller than the element at the head of the size 3 array. Then assume that all the 3 element is smaller than the last element of the size 1000 array. I should be able to get 1002 comparisons. Is this the maximum comparison? What approach can I take to solve it. For now I am just guessing some values.

Comment: http://sorting.at/ sorting algorithm visualizer site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's O(n+m). Worstcase each of the elements of each of the arrays will be compared with something.

You can have a look at the algorithm described with the similar question [Time complexity for merging two sorted arrays of size n and m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039217/time-complexity-for-merging-two-sorted-arrays-of-size-n-and-m). Best case you spend a lot of time in 'copy rest' section, worst case you have to advance counters for both arrays until the full length. Feel free to ask more specific questions.

You can calculate a particular number by considering a particular dataset. E.g. for `A{1001,1002,1003}` and `B{1,2, ..., 999, 1005}`. Worst case is achieved by having 'copy rest' piece exercised for just the last element (i.e. the strict number is n+m-1).

```
999 comparisons: A{1001} vs B{1,..,999} -> B elements merged
1 comparison: A{1001} vs B{1005} -> A merged
1 comparison: A{1002} vs B{1005} -> A merged
1 comparison: A{1003} vs B{1005} -> A merged
```

we're done with A at this point and last element of B is merged using 'copy rest' piece

Comment: Is the answer 1003, if it is n+m? I can't seems to visualise it to reach 1003.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a particular dataset for your numbers