# merging and sorting 2 sorted arrays with big o looking for clarification.

Tags: java, arrays, big-o

This is a school work.  I am not looking for code help but since my teacher isn't helping I came here.

I am asked to merge and sort two sorted arrays following two cases:

1. When sizes of the two arrays are equal
2. When sizes of the two arrays are different

Now I have done case 2 which also does case 1 :/ I just don't get it how I could write a code for case 1 or how it could differ from case 2. array length doesn't connect with the problem or I am not understanding correctly.

Then I am asked to compute big(o).

I am not looking for code here. If anyone by any chance understands what my teacher is asking really please give me hints to solve it.

Comment: Just search u will find how to merge two sorted arrays and yes if u do it correctly size wont matter but if u choose wrong approch i can figure out how it could fail dor different size array grind for it not that difficult

Comment: @VIPER have already done it correctly and in my method size doesn't matter. Can you elaborate on how to do the one that fails with size changes? please!

Comment: This post should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039217/time-complexity-for-merging-two-sorted-arrays-of-size-n-and-m and I don't think both cases are different. Case 1 is just a special case of Case 2 where m and n are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging two sorted arrays is a linear complexity operation. This means in terms of Big-O notation it is O(m+n) where m and n are lengths of two sorted arrays.

So when you say the `array length doesn't connect with the problem` your understanding is correct. Irrespective of the lengths of two sorted arrays the merging of these arrays involves taking elements from each sorted array and comparing them and copying the one to new array(depending whether you want the merged sorted array in ascending or descending order) and incrementing the counter of the array from which you copied the element to new sorted array.

Comment: But I do have to implement two methods one that takes equal array lengths. I can't think of an algorithm that depends on size1 = size2. I have already solved the one that takes different array sizes.

Comment: Since, lengths doesn't have any role in sorting two sorted arrays you can reuse your algo.

Comment: maybe my teacher is just trying to show us that sizes don't matter in relation to big(o). :/ who knows

Comment: Yes he might be interested in students figuring that out. While learning DS&A it's important to think and from the question it seems your teacher wants that. Will serve you good in long term.

Answer (score 2):

It is very good to learn instead of copying.
as you suggest, there is no difference between case 1 and 2 but the worst case of algorithms depend on your solution. So I describe my solution (no code) and give you its worst case.
You can in both case, the arrays must ends with infinity so add infinity to them. then iterate over all of elements of each array, at each time, pick the one which is smaller and put in in your result array (merge of tow arrays).
With this solution, you can calculate worst case easily. we must iterate both of arrays once, and we add a infinity to both of them, if their length is n and m so our worst and best case is `O(m + n)` (you do `m + n + 2 - 1` comparison and -1 because you don't compare the end of both array, I mean infinity)

but why adding infinity add the end of array? because for that we must make a copy of array with one more space? it is one way and worst case of that is `O(m + n)` for copying arrays too. but there is another solution too. you can compare until you get at the end of array, then you must add the rest of array which is not compared completely to end of your result array. but with infinity, it is automatic.

I hope helped you. if there is something wrong, comment it.

Comment: There are no constants in Big-O, so it is _O(m + n)_

Comment: NOTE: O(m + n + 2 - 1) is O(m + n) which is O(max(m, n))

Comment: Yes. I know. it is only for describe it better. I edit it.

Comment: @Amin thanks for your answer byt what do you exactly mean by "add a infinity at the end of both arrays" ? I dont get that part

Comment: I mean if you have array [1, 2, 3] then make a copy of that and create [1, 2, 3, infinity] which infinity is a big number (like `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `Double.MAX_VALUE`)

Comment: @Amin: How does adding a very large value at the end of array matter? After all it will just be compared only.

Comment: it is only for make it easy for just one pass. I update my post, you can read it and wee why we do this. it is for case when two array has different size.

Comment: @Amin my whole problem is how to make an algorithm that is size dependent and in this case where array1.length equals array2.length. I have already created a method that does case 2

Comment: you mean you want an solution for merge two sorted array with equal size (n) independent of size? (O(1)) this is not your question you asked but if you want this, I don't think it is possible to merge two array in O(1) otherwise mergeSort can be more faster.

Comment: @Amin a solution that fails if the 2 arrays have different lengths.

Comment: can you give example? and which way? (infinity or other) I can't give a code so I can only explain. I hope that I can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this question is to look at each array as having a head and a tail, and solving the problem recursively. This way, we can use a base case, two arrays of size 1, to sort through the entirety of the two arrays m and n. Since both arrays are already sorted, simply compare the two heads of each array and add the element that comes first to your newly-created merged array, and move to the next element in that array. Your function will call itself again after adding the element. This will keep happening until one of the two arrays is empty. Now, you can simply add what is left of the nonempty array to the end of your merged array, and you are done.

I'm not sure if your professor will allow you to use recursive calls, but this method could make the coding much easier. Runtime would still be O(m+n), as you are basically iterating through both arrays once.

Hope this helps.